# Continue sleeping for remaining time when thread is interrupted

Tags: java, multithreading, sleep

I have network requirement who forces me to idle request sending for 2 seconds

```
requester = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
                  buildRequest();
                  Thread.sleep(requestDelay);
                } catch( InterruptedException e){
                   // keep idle for the remaining time still
                   // interrupted at 1s need to sleep 1 second more
                   e.printStackTrace();
                }
                sendRequest();
            }
        }
```

Is it possible to still sleep for remaining time with consuming CPU with a loop? If yes is the best way ?

Comment: Of course it's possible, but it would be best not to sleep at all. Use a reactive pattern to fire an even after a few minutes to wake the request - that way you don't "waste" threads.

Comment: Interrupts don’t happen by accident.  If your thread is interrupted, someone is explicitly asking it to stop what it’s doing and exit gracefully.  Are you sure you want to ignore that?

Comment: Guava has [`Uninterruptibles.sleepUninterruptibly`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Uninterruptibles.html#sleepUninterruptibly(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)). Basically, it just records the fact the thread was interrupted, clears the flag, and goes back to sleep. Once the full time has expired, it re-interrupts if it was interrupted.

Comment: I know that sleep would be a bad idea from the start. But given this option, would be another sleep appropriate in the catch scope from the remaining time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want to handle the `InterruptedException` in such way to unsure a delay before executing `sendRequest`. Well, since the `InterruptedException` happens when something calls `interrupt()` on the thread, that catch block doesn't get executed so you don't have to worry about.

Your approach is not quite right, a reactive approach would be better. Even a basic [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) is better.